# how to make scrollable div below a fixed navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

the expected outcome looks like this:
[not on top of the navbar, start from the bottom of the navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5isi.jpg)

instead of:
[start from the very top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB1X0.jpg)

I want it to be inside a DIV only.

Here's part of my code:

```
<div>
  <navbar style=" position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 70px"/>
  <div style="margin-top:80px">
    I want a scroll right in this DIV. 
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Then you would have to create a div with a fixed vertical height that surrounds the whole page, so perhaps the <body> tag. Then you would have to create two <div>'s one with the navbar in, the other with `overflow-y: scroll;` to achieve this. But without your code, I can't provide you a direct answer/solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved with both top position or padding/margin. **Check my working snippet:**

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar{
  height: 60px; /* notice this value */
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.myScrollableDiv {
   position: fixed;
   top: 60px; /* same height as navbar */
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   background: green;
   color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar"></div>
<div class="myScrollableDiv">
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

**On your scaffolding:**

```html
<div style="height: 100%">
  <navbar style=" position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 70px;
   background: red"/>
  <div style="margin-top:0px; margin-top: 70px; overflow-y: scroll; height: 100px">
    I want a scroll right in this DIV. <br />
    I want a scroll right in this DIV. <br />
    I want a scroll right in this DIV. <br />
    I want a scroll right in this DIV. <br />
    I want a scroll right in this DIV. <br />
    I want a scroll right in this DIV. <br />
    I want a scroll right in this DIV. <br />
    I want a scroll right in this DIV. <br />
    I want a scroll right in this DIV. <br />
    I want a scroll right in this DIV. <br />
    I want a scroll right in this DIV. <br />
    I want a scroll right in this DIV. <br />
    I want a scroll right in this DIV. <br />
    I want a scroll right in this DIV. <br />
    I want a scroll right in this DIV. <br />
        
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Nice! But I can't keep 'position: fixed' this property. Is there any other way to achieve it without"position: fixed"?

Comment: I'll add another snippet with your code, give me a minute